# nginx pass url arguments with ampersand

Tags: nginx

The website is currently showing the location of http://www.example.com/ when visiting this url http://www.example.com/edit.html&edit=10486 
I'm trying to pass this part of url as arguments to index.php "edit.html&edit=10486"

My existing configuration is:

```
    index index.php;
    location / {
            root /home/example.com/public_html;
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
            }
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                    return 404;
            }

            # This is a robust solution for path info security issue and works with cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1 in /etc/php.ini (default)
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9031;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are missing the "?" after edit.html. To pass the query string parameters the URL should be http://www.example.com/edit.html?edit=10486

Comment: great this works :) please submit this as an answer

Comment: I have submitted it as an answer. Could you please mark it as correct. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the "?" after edit.html. To pass the query string parameter the URL should be `http://example.com/edit.html?edit=10486`